# How to dynamically manage prometheus file_sd_configs in docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, prometheus, service-discovery

I have been using `targets.json` inside a node.js application running locally to dynamically add ip addresses for prometheus to probe service discovery as file_sd_configs option. It has worked well. I was able add new ip's and execute the prometheus reload api from the node app, monitor those ip's and issue alerts(with blackbox and alertmanager).

However, now the application and prometheus are running inside docker on same network. How can I make my node application write to a file(or update it) inside a folder in prometheus container?

Comment: One of the strong point of Prometheus is the ability to use cloud native service discovery. Depending on your flavor of orchestration, you can usually use the API to discover services.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `target.json` file to the Prometheus and the application container by adding a volume mapping to your docker-compose file.

```
 volumes:
  - /hostpath/target.json:/containerpath/target.json
```

Instead of using a mapped hostsystem folder you can also use named volumes, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) for more information about docker volumes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that approach.